Merging Vite frontend Istanbul coverage reports discrepancy
I have an issue where I am trying to generate code coverage for both the unit tests and E2E tests in my React application using Vite and Istanbul.
For the E2E tests I am serving the application and then accessing the window.__coverage__ to get the report.
When generating an HTML report for both of these the results seem fine, however when I merge these two, the statements and line numbers seem to, no longer seem to make sense. I'd expect that when merging the amount of statements, branches, functions and lines would be the same or at the very least a sum of both the test coverage results. For example 6 lines in the unit tests 8 in the E2E tests results in 32 lines once merged.
The following show the unit tests, E2E tests and merged result coverage:
Code Coverage Report
Code Coverage Report App.tsx
vite.config.ts:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import istanbul from 'vite-plugin-istanbul'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    istanbul({
      include: 'src/*',
      exclude: ['node_modules', 'tests/'],
      extension: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
      requireEnv: false,
    }),
  ],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: './src/setupTests.ts',
    coverage: {
      provider: 'istanbul',
      reporter: ['text', 'html', 'json'],
      include: 'src/*',
      reportsDirectory: 'coverage_unit',
    },
  },
});

package.json:
{
  "name": "coverage-merge",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc -b && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "coverage": "vitest run --coverage"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.9.0",
    "@testing-library/dom": "^10.4.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.1",
    "@vitest/coverage-istanbul": "^2.1.1",
    "eslint": "^9.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^5.1.0-rc.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.9",
    "globals": "^15.9.0",
    "jsdom": "^25.0.1",
    "nyc": "^17.1.0",
    "typescript": "^5.5.3",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "vite": "^5.4.1",
    "vite-plugin-istanbul": "^6.0.2",
    "vitest": "^2.1.1"
  }
}

To generate the reports I run yarn nyc report --reporter=html and add the coverage.json files in the .nyc_output folder.
